# two way binding with null check

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

In data binding adatper, i want to check if `int` value in my model is not zero. Because hint is never shown, if value is 0 default then 0 is shown as text. I want to show hint if value is zero.

**Below works well without checking 0 int value**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/port"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="@={`` + item.port}"
                />
```

**I tried this which does not work**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/port"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text='@={item.port != 0 ? `` + item.port : ""}'
                />
```

`item.port` is `int`value

Any suggestions to make this work **with only data binding**?

Comment: What type `item.port` is?

Comment: @H.Taras it is int

Comment: Is it something like flag for using hint or what purpose of it?

Comment: It is two way binding, if i change value in editext then model int value should be changed

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll need a `BindingAdapter/InverseBindingAdapter` or a conversion method. The easiest is probably a conversion method:

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <data>
        <import type="com.example.mount.teststuff.Conversion"/>
        <variable name="port" type="int"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={Conversion.intToString(port, port)}"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{`` + port}"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And in your Conversion class you'd have something like this:

```
public class Conversion {
    @InverseMethod("stringToInt")
    public static String intToString(int oldValue, int value) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static int stringToInt(int oldValue, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I just updated the answer to include my tested layout and code. You can look for more detail on [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-inverse-functions-95aab4b11873).

Comment: Gradle build failed after using Conversion class in text param.

Comment: Also bad thing is build shows error in binding class, it does not tell what is issue.

Comment: Did you import the `Conversion` class? I'm not sure why it failed.

Comment: Yes i imported :/, can you check it with dummy data

Comment: I just tried this exact code and had no trouble with it. I'll update the answer with the full code.

Answer (score 1):

`<import type="Integer"/>`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/port"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text='@={item.port}'
                />
```

Dont keep port variable as int as two way binding required String type Setter for port value. Instead convert String value into Integer in XML itself.

Update : Instead of checking null for hint, please change port value from your viewmodel. if port is 0 then you can replace it with empty string "" and then call notifyPropertyChange(BR.port);

Comment: That can be a solution. You checked int 0 in hint. Cool

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Comment: I think this error occurred in hint when there in no value in string port.

Comment: I have changed item.port from integer to string, as you said